# ERROR:tornado.general:Could not open static file

Tags: javascript, tornado

I'm writing a tornado web app and have a file named "static" with files such as main.js, require.js, elasticsearch.js, and d3.v3.js. The last three are just source code for the javascript libraries.

In my index.html file I have the lines

```
    <script>src={{ static_url("scripts/require.js") }}></script>
    <script>require([{{ static_url("scripts/main.js") }}], function () {})</script>
```

Now when I run the app, I get two errors:

```
ERROR:tornado.general:Could not open static file '...'
```

for each of my two files that I'm reading in. Has anyone ever had a similar issue or have any insights as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are the `js` files directly in the `static` directory or in a `scripts` subdirectory? Assuming you did something like `static_path="static"` when creating the application, the files need to live in `static/scripts/*.js` to match the paths you use in your `static_url` call.