# Visdom shows nothing

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, conda, visdom

After starting the visdom server and opening it in the browser i only get a blue screen and the following errors:

ERROR:tornado.general:Could not open static file 'C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\visdom\static\js\react-grid-layout.min.js'
                                                                                                 ERROR:tornado.general:Could not open static file 'C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\visdom\static\js\plotly.min.js'

Any idea why is this happening and how can i solve it?

Comment: Similar ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699159/errortornado-generalcould-not-open-static-file

Comment: Similiar, unfortunately not helpful, the paths already match

Comment: Is this a known issue ? https://github.com/facebookresearch/visdom/issues/397, https://github.com/facebookresearch/visdom/issues/111 I hope the resolution methods discussed here might help fix the issue